# On screen keyboard is not changing when changing language

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I would like to be able to use the on screen keyboard to type in Arabic on my Ubuntu 20.4 machine. I added the language to the input source and it works if I use my actual keyboard. The problem is the on screen keyboard does not change its language even though I chose a different one from the keyboard layout. The language simply stays in English even though Arabic is listed on the language option in the on screen keyboard. It would not change.
I restarted gnome but it did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

- Disable the *Screen Keyboard*
- Switch to the Arabic keyboard layout
- Enable the *Screen Keyboard*

That should give you an Arabic on screen keyboard.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately it did not work either following the instructions you gave me. I also added German and the the Germany keyboard I get on the onscreen keyboard is not correct (It does not have äüöß)

Comment: @Fadi: Weird. As regards German, you need to long press `a` to see e.g. `ä`, long press `s` to see `ß`, etc.

Comment: @Fadi: How do you go about disabling the Screen Keyboard?

Comment: I configured a shortcut to turn the on-screen keyboard on and off. I did that in the settings --> keyboard shortcuts --> turn on screen keyboard on or off.
When I choose the language in the language menu, I can get Arabic and it works well but the on-screen keyboard is not changing at all. I noticed it only works when I choose English or German.
As for German, I did not know that I have to long press the buttons to get the special characters. Thank you for that